# Undefined 'this.variable' during runtime debugging in callback in Angular 4 Typescript App

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, rxjs

My SO friends,

I have started working on a Angular4 app and came across the following (webpack?) odd behaviour. When runtime-debugging in chrome inside the callback of the observable `getHistory` (an API call), `this.varTimeSeries` shows as undefined when I hover over it.

`Console.log(this.varTimeSeries)` logs the correct object in the console though.

You can see I am correctly using the fat arrow syntax `=>` that should return the Component's `this` inside the callback.

Any ideas why this happens?

```
public getHistory() {

    this.varHistoryService.getHistory(this.selectedConfig.NAME)
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.varTimeSeries = res;
            console.log(this.varTimeSeries);
        },
        errors => {
            console.log(errors);
        });
}
```

This is what my `tsconfig.webpack.json` file looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "Client/**/*.spec.ts",
    "Client/**/*.e2e.ts"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "./compiled",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you place your breakpoint? At which point are you getting `undefined`?

Comment: How do you call `getHistory`?

Comment: I call getHistory() from a button in the html `<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getHistory()" [disabled]="newPreset">Go</button>` @yurzui

Comment: The breakpoint is placed right on `console.log(this.varTimeSeries)` @Saravana

Answer (score 2):

The issue was in the `tsconfig.json` file which was incorrectly referencing es5!

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "devtool": "source-map",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "jasmine",
      "node",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "compiled"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

Comment: This answer still seems valid. I was getting an undefined value during runtime, but was getting expected results in debugger. Checked the target in my tsconfig.json was es5, changed to es6 and worked as expected. Note, I used the command *ng new <project-name>* to create the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
public getHistory() {

    this.varHistoryService.getHistory(this.selectedConfig.NAME)
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.varTimeSeries = res;
            console.log(this.varTimeSeries);
        },
        errors => {
            console.log(errors);
        });
}.bind(this)
```